# Hide and show elements using css

Tags: css, wordpress

I am making my first steps learning html, css and php. I made some courses on internet and now I decided to make a site using Wordpress so I can continue learning from the practice.

The thing is that I made a page with a custom field for a video and a custom field for a description.

[image]
As you can see in the picture I'm hiding all the text of the description using a details tag called About in html.

When I click on about I see this:

[image]

And there is my question: 
How can I hide some elements when other elements are displayed? I would like to open this page and only see the text and a close button. It means that when details is open, the page should not display the "menu" link and the "strange magic" title.

I already tryied this but it doesn't work:

```
details[open] .entry-title .menu-toggle{
    display: none;
}
```

Do you have some suggestion? It is something possible to do using css?

Comment: Is `jQuery` available? I would think you are going to need to use it

Comment: Maybe I can use an if else statement in my functions.js document? Do you have some example? Have a reference would be nice for me! thank you

Comment: JavaScript is the way to go and functions.js sounds like the place to put your code. You would need the following logic:
Add an eventListener to the "About"-link. When the link is clicked, show/hide the text based on it's current state : https://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/showhide-element/

Comment: Thank you very much for this. I will take a look at it.

Comment: So there no exist something in css equivalent to a conditional?

Comment: You could try to do it with CSS selectors but it would probably be much more complicated than with JS. And you seem to use JS anyways in order display the text when clicking "About". Why not use it for the rest too.

Comment: Without the code it's difficult to say how you can do, depends the order of the elements maybe with selector is possible to do. An idea that occurs to me is that the div that containing the text take over all the space and cover the menu

Comment: That's a good solution and it works. I change the color and the z-index of the div that contains all the text and now it covers the menu. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

I think you should try this, maybe it will help you..

```
label {
  display:block;
  margin:20px 0 10px 0;
}
label:hover {
  text-decoration:underline;
}
input {
  position:absolute;
  left:-999em
}
.hide {
  width:50%;
  border:1px solid #000;
  background:rgba(148, 148, 148, 0.33);
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 10px;
  max-height:999em;
  opacity:1;
  height:auto;
  overflow:hidden;
  transition:opacity .5s linear;
}
.hide p {
  padding:10px;
  margin:0
}
input[type=checkbox]:checked + div {
  opacity:0;
  max-height:0;
  border:none;
  transition:opacity .5s linear, max-height .5s linear;
}
.follow{
  border-top:1px solid blue;margin:0;
}
```

**Demo**: https://jsfiddle.net/Pratik_009/t41nn2nh/